# Final Element of Array Throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

I'm running the below code in Apps Script. This snippet is supposed to copy the data from several cells from one Google Sheet ('Entry Form') into a new variable called `copyData` and then paste those same values, one by one, into another sheet ('SCAR Log'). I've determined that this error only occurs when my final array value `entryFormData[44][0]` is blank. The script only throws this error when the final data cell on my 'Entry Form' is blank.

Strangely, I'm using a nearly exact replica of this code on another sheet that is working perfectly, regardless of whether or not the last array value is blank. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

```
if (responseOverwrite == uiOverwrite.Button.OK) {
          var copyData = 
          [[entryFormData[4][3],       //SCAR No
            entryFormData[4][12],      //PO No.
            entryFormData[8][2],       //Date Opened
            entryFormData[8][8],       //Originator
            entryFormData[8][18],      //Supplier
            entryFormData[10][6],      //Supplier Quality Representative
            entryFormData[10][18],     //SQR Email
            entryFormData[13][0],      //Drawing No(s). / Part No(s).
            entryFormData[13][11],     //Serial No(s). / Lot No(s).
            entryFormData[13][20],     //Job Code(s)
            entryFormData[18][0],      //Description of Problem
            entryFormData[18][13],     //Root Cause
            entryFormData[23][0],      //Immediate Corrective Action
            entryFormData[23][13],     //Preventative Action Plan
            entryFormData[25][9],      //Failure Analysis Conducted by Supplier
            entryFormData[29][6],      //Date of Supplier Response
            entryFormData[29][17],     //Supplier Action Type
            entryFormData[32][0],      //Description of Supplier Actions
            entryFormData[34][7],      //Supplier Response Assessment
            entryFormData[34][20],     //Assessed by (QA/QM)
            entryFormData[37][0],      //Assessment Rationale
            entryFormData[37][21],     //Problem Resolved
            entryFormData[41][2],      //NCP No(s).
            entryFormData[41][9],      //RMA No(s).
            entryFormData[41][18],     //Other
            entryFormData[44][0]]];   //Comments and Recommendations
          destination.getRange("A" + row + ":Z" + row).setValues(copyData);
          break;
        }
```

For clarity, here's the full Apps Script with the rest of the code:

```
function Save() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName('SCAR Log');
  var lastDataRow = destination.getLastRow();
  var firstBlankDataRow = destination.getLastRow()+1;
  var scarLogData = destination.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var uiOverwrite = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var uiSaveNew = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var entryFormData = ss.getSheetByName('Entry Form').getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var currentSCARNo = ss.getRange('D5').getDisplayValue();
  var filename = "SCAR-" + currentSCARNo;
  var currentFormFieldsColor = ss.getRange('C9').getBackground();
  var formFieldsArray = ['M5', 'C9', 'S9', 'I9', 'G11', 'S11', 'A14', 'L14', 'U14', 'A19', 'N19', 'A24', 'N24', 'J26', 'G30', 'R30', 'A33', 'H35', 'U35', 'A38', 'V38', 'C42', 'J42', 'S42', 'A45'];
  var formFieldsData = ss.getRangeList(formFieldsArray).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());

  // If form field data is not found (but 24 or 25 commas are found)...
  if (formFieldsData == ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," || formFieldsData ==  ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️ Nothing to Save.", "Please complete this SCAR or click \"Clear\" and then select an existing SCAR No. from the \"SCAR No.\" drop-down and press \"Edit\".", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
  }

  //Check if we are in View Mode
  if (currentFormFieldsColor == '#b7b7b7') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('⚠️ You are currently in View Mode. This data has already been saved.');
    return;
  }

  // Ensure SCAR No. on Entry Form is not blank.
  if (entryFormData[4][3] != "") {

    // Check column [0] of each SCAR Log row for a matching SCAR No.
    for (var i in scarLogData) {
      var row = parseInt(i) + 1;
      
      // Matching SCAR No. Found
      if (scarLogData[i][0] == entryFormData[4][3]) {
        Logger.log("Found a match for \"" + "SCAR NO. " + currentSCARNo + "\" in row #" + row + " on the \"SCAR Log\" sheet");
        
        // Overwrite?
        var responseOverwrite = uiOverwrite.alert('⚠️ Overwrite Existing Data?', 'CAR No. ' + currentSCARNo + ' already exists. Would you like to overwrite the log with the data in this form?', uiOverwrite.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

        // YES - Overwrite
        if (responseOverwrite == uiOverwrite.Button.OK) {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
          var copyData = 
          [[entryFormData[4][3],       //SCAR No
            entryFormData[4][12],      //PO No.
            entryFormData[8][2],       //Date Opened
            entryFormData[8][8],       //Originator
            entryFormData[8][18],      //Supplier
            entryFormData[10][6],      //Supplier Quality Representative
            entryFormData[10][18],     //SQR Email
            entryFormData[13][0],      //Drawing No(s). / Part No(s).
            entryFormData[13][11],     //Serial No(s). / Lot No(s).
            entryFormData[13][20],     //Job Code(s)
            entryFormData[18][0],      //Description of Problem
            entryFormData[18][13],     //Root Cause
            entryFormData[23][0],      //Immediate Corrective Action
            entryFormData[23][13],     //Preventative Action Plan
            entryFormData[25][9],      //Failure Analysis Conducted by Supplier
            entryFormData[29][6],      //Date of Supplier Response
            entryFormData[29][17],     //Supplier Action Type
            entryFormData[32][0],      //Description of Supplier Actions
            entryFormData[34][7],      //Supplier Response Assessment
            entryFormData[34][20],     //Assessed by (QA/QM)
            entryFormData[37][0],      //Assessment Rationale
            entryFormData[37][21],     //Problem Resolved
            entryFormData[41][2],      //NCP No(s).
            entryFormData[41][9],      //RMA No(s).
            entryFormData[41][18],     //Other
            entryFormData[44][0]]];   //Comments and Recommendations
          destination.getRange("A" + row + ":Z" + row).setValues(copyData);
          ss.toast(entryFormData[44][0]);
          break;
        }

        else if (responseOverwrite == uiOverwrite.Button.CANCEL) {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "Cancel" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
          ss.toast(" Nothing was saved.");
          return;
        }

        else 
        ss.toast(" Nothing was saved.");
        return;
      }

      // Last Data Row; Matching SCAR No. NOT Found.
      else if (row == lastDataRow) {

        Logger.log("Did not find a match for \"" + "SCAR NO. " + currentSCARNo + " on the \"SCAR Log\" sheet");

        // Save New and Clear.

        Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
        ss.toast(entryFormData[41][2]);
        var copyData = [[entryFormData[4][3],     //SCAR No
          entryFormData[4][12],          //PO No.
          entryFormData[8][2],          //Date Opened
          entryFormData[8][8],          //Originator
          entryFormData[8][18],          //Supplier
          entryFormData[10][6],          //Supplier Quality Representative
          entryFormData[10][18],          //SQR Email
          entryFormData[13][0],          //Drawing No(s). / Part No(s).
          entryFormData[13][11],          //Serial No(s). / Lot No(s).
          entryFormData[13][20],          //Job Code(s)
          entryFormData[18][0],          //Description of Problem
          entryFormData[18][13],          //Root Cause
          entryFormData[23][0],          //Immediate Corrective Action
          entryFormData[23][13],          //Preventative Action Plan
          entryFormData[25][9],          //Failure Analysis Conducted by Supplier
          entryFormData[29][6],          //Date of Supplier Response
          entryFormData[29][17],          //Supplier Action Type
          entryFormData[32][0],          //Description of Supplier Actions
          entryFormData[34][7],          //Supplier Response Assessment
          entryFormData[34][20],          //Assessed by (QA/QM)
          entryFormData[37][0],          //Assessment Rationale
          entryFormData[37][21],          //Problem Resolved
          entryFormData[41][2],          //NCP No(s).
          entryFormData[41][9],          //RMA No(s).
          entryFormData[41][18],          //Other
          entryFormData[44][0]]];          //Comments and Recommendations
        destination.getRange("A" + firstBlankDataRow + ":Z" + firstBlankDataRow).setValues(copyData);
        ss.toast(" " + filename + " was saved to the Log on row " + firstBlankDataRow + ".");
        break;
      }
    }

    // Set the data validation for cell D5 of active sheet to require value from ddSheet A3:A, with dropdown menu.
    var ddSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Entry Form.Drop Downs (HS)');
    var ddCell = ss.getRange('D5');
    var ddRange = ddSheet.getRange('A3:A');
    var ddRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(ddRange, true).build();

    // define the total Entry Form range for setValues
    var destinationEntryForm = ss.getSheetByName('Entry Form');
    var efRange = destinationEntryForm.getRange(1,1,45,23);

    // get the array values
    var efValues = efRange.getValues();


    // adjust some array values
      efValues[4][12] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:B,2,0),"")';     //PO No.
      efValues[8][2] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:C,3,0),"")';     //Date Opened
      efValues[8][8] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:D,4,0),"")';     //Originator
      efValues[8][18] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:E,5,0),"")';     //Supplier
      efValues[10][6] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:F,6,0),"")';     //Supplier Quality Representative
      efValues[10][18] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:G,7,0),"")';     //SQR Email
      efValues[13][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:H,8,0),"")';     //Drawing No(s). / Part No(s).
      efValues[13][11] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:I,9,0),"")';     //Serial No(s). / Lot No(s).
      efValues[13][20] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:J,10,0),"")';     //Job Code(s)
      efValues[18][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:K,11,0),"")';     //Description of Problem
      efValues[18][13] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:L,12,0),"")';     //Root Cause
      efValues[23][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:M,13,0),"")';     //Immediate Corrective Action
      efValues[23][13] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:N,13,0),"")';     //Preventative Action Plan
      efValues[25][9] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:O,15,0),"")';     //Failure Analysis Conducted by Supplier
      efValues[29][6] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:P,16,0),"")';     //Date of Supplier Response
      efValues[29][17] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:Q,17,0),"")';     //Supplier Action Type
      efValues[32][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:R,18,0),"")';     //Description of Supplier Actions
      efValues[34][7] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:S,19,0),"")';     //Supplier Response Assessment
      efValues[34][20] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:T,20,0),"")';     //Assessed by (QA/QM)
      efValues[37][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:U,21,0),"")';     //Assessment Rationale
      efValues[37][21] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:V,22,0),"")';     //Problem Resolved
      efValues[41][2] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:W,23,0),"")';     //NCP No(s).
      efValues[41][9] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:X,24,0),"")';     //RMA No(s).
      efValues[41][18] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:Y,25,0),"")';     //Other
      efValues[44][0] = '=iferror(vlookup(D5,\'SCAR Log\'!A:Z,26,0),"")';     //Comments and Recommendations

    // update the range for the adjusted array values
    efRange.setValues(efValues);

    //Show Drop Down Arrow on Cell D5
    ddCell.setDataValidation(ddRule);

    //Set background color to gray
    ss.getRangeList(['M5', 'C9', 'S9', 'I9', 'G11', 'S11', 'A14', 'L14', 'U14', 'A19', 'N19', 'A24', 'N24', 'J26', 'G30', 'R30', 'A33', 'H35', 'U35', 'A38', 'V38', 'C42', 'J42', 'S42', 'A45']).setBackground('#b7b7b7');

  }
  else {
   
    // Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️ Nothing to Save", "Please select a SCAR No. from the \"SCAR No.\" drop-down and press \"Edit\" or click \"New\" to begin a new report.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting `entryFormData`, `getDataRange()`, `getRange(1,1,xx.getLastRow(),xx.getLastColumn())` or some other way?

Comment: I just updated the original question with the full script. Thanks so much for taking a look @TheWizEd.

Comment: If you are using `getDataRange()` and line 45 is empty then there are only 44 rows or `entryFormData[43]' is the last row in the array.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, if there are additional cells with non-empty values on lines further down the Google Sheet from which I'm pulling values to create the array, `getDataRange()` will see any empty values up to the final non-empty cell and it will not throw the error. BUT, if there are no more values on the Google Sheet, `getDataRange()` will stop looking at empty cells and will throw the error because the remainder of the range is just empty values. Is that correct?

Comment: `getDataRange()` returns all rows up to and including the last row containing any value.  And rows in between with no values will also be included in the array.  `getRange(1,1,xx.getLastRow(),xx.getLastColumn())` does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a million! I should have reached out yesterday and saved myself a 24 hours of time. Thank you again!! If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it, as you certainly deserve the credit.